# get the current date from GMT

Tags: javascript, datetime

I want to get the date from the GMT time but it returns the date which is one day ahead. How can I get the date mentioned in the GMT string always?

```
new Date("Mon, 27 Aug 2018 22:00:00 GMT").getDate()
```

This command returns `28` as the output, but I want `27`.
Is there anything I need to add?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this One.I think your problem will be solved.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getUTCDate();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome..
Stay Connected

Answer (score 1):

When you create a `new Date()`  the browser returns date based on your device timezone. You can use `Date.getTimezoneOffset()`  to get GMT offset time difference and then adjust the time by multiplying the value.

```js
// Your date
var myDate = new Date("Mon, 27 Aug 2018 22:00:00 GMT")

// Convert your date to local using  getTimezoneOffset() and multiply with 60000 to get time adjusted GMT 0

var myDateLocal =new Date( myDate.valueOf() + myDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000 ).getDate();


document.getElementById("myDate").innerHTML=myDateLocal;
```

```html
<h1 id="myDate" ></h1>
```